# Code Review with Visual Studio 2015 and TFS

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, visual-studio-2015, atlassian-crucible

We are running TFS and VS2015. Crucible does not support TFS. Is there another product for doing code reviews? similar to Crucible?

Comment: TFS has built in support for code reviews (TFVC) or pull requests (git).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use Visual Studio to ask someone else from your team to review it. Your request will show up in his team explorer, in the 'my work' page. More detail steps for you reference: [Get your code reviewed with Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/tfvc/get-code-reviewed-vs?view=azure-devops)

If you want people on your team to review code in a Git team project, you can use a pull request to review and merge the code. More info from MSDN: [Conduct a Git pull request](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/pull-requests?view=tfs-2015)

If you are looking for plug-in tools for Visual Studio, here is a good one: [Review Assistant](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=DevartSoftware.ReviewAssistant-CodeReviewTool)

Comment: Review Assistant it's a good tool, and its free until 3 users.